# Correct usage of gpus-per-task for allocation of distinct GPUs via SLURM

Tags: gpu, cluster-computing, nvidia, slurm

I am using the [`cons_tres`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cons_res.html) SLURM plugin, which introduces, among other things, the `--gpus-per-task` option. If my understanding is correct, the following script should allocate two *distinct* GPUs on the same node:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:2
#SBATCH --gpus-per-task=1

srun --ntasks=2 --gres=gpu:1 nvidia-smi -L
```

However, it doesn't, as the output is

```
GPU 0: Tesla V100-SXM3-32GB (UUID: GPU-c55b3036-d54d-a885-7c6c-4238840c836e)
GPU 0: Tesla V100-SXM3-32GB (UUID: GPU-c55b3036-d54d-a885-7c6c-4238840c836e)
```

What gives?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55029430/10260561

**Edit**

Alternatively, the `srun` command could be

```sh
srun --ntasks=1 --gres=gpu:1 nvidia-smi -L &
srun --ntasks=1 --gres=gpu:1 nvidia-smi -L &
wait
```

ie, run the two tasks in parallel, each on 1 GPU. This also doesn't work, and gives

```
GPU 0: Tesla V100-SXM3-32GB (UUID: GPU-c55b3036-d54d-a885-7c6c-4238840c836e)
srun: Job 627 step creation temporarily disabled, retrying
srun: Step created for job 627
GPU 0: Tesla V100-SXM3-32GB (UUID: GPU-c55b3036-d54d-a885-7c6c-4238840c836e)
```

Leaving out the extra parameters and calling `srun nvidia-smi -L` results in

```
GPU 0: Tesla V100-SXM3-32GB (UUID: GPU-c55b3036-d54d-a885-7c6c-4238840c836e)
GPU 1: Tesla V100-SXM3-32GB (UUID: GPU-ce697126-4112-a696-ff6b-1b072cdf03a2)
GPU 0: Tesla V100-SXM3-32GB (UUID: GPU-c55b3036-d54d-a885-7c6c-4238840c836e)
GPU 1: Tesla V100-SXM3-32GB (UUID: GPU-ce697126-4112-a696-ff6b-1b072cdf03a2)
```

ie, 4 tasks are being run?

I need to run two tasks in parallel on distinct GPUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I want

```sh
srun --gres=gpu:1 bash -c 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$SLURM_PROCID env' | grep CUDA_VISIBLE

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

but doesn't make use of `--gpus-per-task`.

Answer (score 2):

All the `#SBATCH`s allocate you two tasks and two GPUs on one node. So far so good. But then you tell `srun` to use both available tasks and only use one GPU. This is why these two tasks have a shared GPU.

To solve it you can leave out the extra parameters when calling srun. It will use all available tasks and GPUs per default.

Comment: You answer runs two tasks, with both GPUs available to each task, whereas I want to run two tasks, with GPU 0 on first taks and GPU 1 on second task.